# SyntaxError: invalid syntax about dict.fromkeys usage

Tags: python

the original code that works.

```
tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'))
```

but when I want to see what is it in the `()`, I got the error message.

```
i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P')
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-58-3979c9c43bba>", line 1
    i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And the code between the parenthese is confusing to me, it seems that the original code is equal to the following code, but why is that?

```
for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode):
    if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'):
        a.append(i)
tbl=dict.fromkeys(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), which normally must be surrounded by parentheses:

```
(i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'))
```

The parentheses are optional when the expression is the only argument to a call, which is why you don't see any for the `dict.fromkeys()` call.

If you want to see what value the generator expression produces, you may want to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead, by replacing the parentheses with square brackets:

```
[i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P')]
```

A generator expression produces a generator, which must be iterated over to get all the values it, while a list comprehension iterates immediately and produces a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!